# Fast JPEG encoding library

Tags: c++, c, encoding, jpeg

anyone know of a free open-source jpeg encoding library for C/C++?  Currently I'm using ImageMagick, which is easy to use, but it's pretty slow.  I compared it to an evaluation of Intel Performance Primitives and the speed of IPP is insane.  Unfortunately it also costs 200$, and I don't need 99% of the IPP).  Also it will only work fast on Intel.

Anyone do any tests?  Any other good libraries out there faster than ImageMagick?

Edit:  I was using 8 bit version of ImageMagick which is supposed to be faster.

Comment: What exactly is "slow"? Can you give numbers?

Comment: At this point no.  All I know is the % CPU use when I just ask it to encode a bunch of images.  I would say IPP is an order of magnitude faster.  But I'm in the process of getting some real numbers.

Comment: Analysis of JPEG Decoding Speeds   http://www.briancbecker.com/blog/2010/analysis-of-jpeg-decoding-speeds/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ImageMagick uses libjpeg (a.k.a Independent JPEG Group library). If you improve the speed of libjpeg, ImageMagick JPEG speed will increase.

There are a few options:

1. Compile an optimized libjpeg. If you have a modern gcc and at least a Pentium 4, you can try `-O3 -msse2` and see if it can boost your speed. Then you can use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or some other way to load your libjpeg instead of the system one.
2. Try out libjpeg-mmx. It is unmaintained, and supposedly buggy and with security flaws, but it may give a speed boost in your case.

Comment: libjpeg-turbo is very stable, and used by most browsers nowadays. Don't bother with the IJG libjpeg.

Answer (score 7):

Check out libjpeg/SIMD, in the trunk of TigerVNC (http://www.tigervnc.com).  We have optimized 64-bit and 32-bit versions which are almost as fast as IPP at compressing/decompressing baseline JPEG:

http://www.mail-archive.com/tigervnc-devel@lists.sourceforge.net/msg00403.html

Comment: I added an article to my wiki about how to build it for various architectures:
http://www.virtualgl.org/DeveloperInfo/Libjpeg

Answer (score 3):

I believe that GIL, which is a library in Boost, contains a way to save image data in JPEG format.  I don't know the speed of it, though.  Given that the library is sponsored by Adobe, I would expect that it's pretty well done.

Comment: Thanks, I missed that one even though I use boost.

Comment: i am not sure but, GIL uses libjpeg for decoding and encoding JPEG, so what matters here is libjpeg's performance..

Comment: GIL is a generic image manipulation library, it does not implement any I/O and compression natively. Instead, as Qubeuc mentioned, it relies on third party libraries. Currently, GIL IO extensions have been implemented for JPEG using libjpeg and PNG using libpng. Perhaps TIFF (libtiff) is also available, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3):

AMD offers [Framewave](http://developer.amd.com/cpu/libraries/framewave), an open sourced alternative to IPP.

Comment: From briefly looking at the API it seems they provide JPEG fundamentals like DCT transform, but I don't see an actual write function that will give me a valid JPEG image.  Have you used it?  Can you point me to the right function?

Comment: Like IPP, Framewave is a library of "chainable" code blocks, not complete tool functions. You have to write/read the binary data yourself.

That said, there is code available for reading & writing JPEG with IPP here: http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-integrated-performance-primitives-code-samples

Framewave is "API-compatible" with IPP, so all that should be needed is replacing the IPP-calls with Framewave-calls. The calls use the exact same naming with different prefixes (fwiEncodeHuffman8x8_JPEG_16s1u_C1 vs. ippiEncodeHuffman8x8_JPEG_16s1u_C1).

Answer (score 1):

If you look around you might find an old version of the Intel JPEG Library. It's not opensource but it is fast. It was fast enough to get 25fps on a 733MHz P-III.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't.  Everyone refers to Intel which of course doesn't provide it any more.  If you have a link, I'd like to have it.

Answer (score 1):

There's also the [Independent JPEG Group](http://www.ijg.org/) which is fairly old and I can't vouch for it's speed. But it should be stable.

Found through [this page](http://www.stereopsis.com/jpg/).

Comment: That's what we use.  It works just fine for what we use it for.

Answer (score 1):

I did some timing encoding a 512x512 jpeg using 100% quality (I know 100% is not lossless).  Basically ImageMagick was only slightly slower than libjpeg.  For 100 images the difference was on the order of 10th of a seconds.  I then got libjpeg with SIMD extension (http://cetus.sakura.ne.jp/softlab/jpeg-x86simd/jpegsimd.html#source) and that thing 6-10 times faster.  Note it really depends on the type of image.  Images with lots of black are really fast, images with detail everywhere are really slow - I believe it's the encoding algorithm.  I may have to give libjpeg-mmx a try because it looks more maintained than the japanese version I got that I don't even know what the license is.

I've also tried to get Framewave to work and couldn't even get it off the ground.  The header files are missing definition of some structure and the forums provide absolutely no support.  I can't believe it's "sponsored by AMD."