# How to make this jpeg compression faster

Tags: c++, opencv

I am using OpenCV to compress binary images from a camera:

```
vector<int> p;

p.push_back(CV_IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY);

p.push_back(75); // JPG quality

vector<unsigned char> jpegBuf;

cv::imencode(".jpg", fIplImageHeader, jpegBuf, p);
```

The code above compresses a binary RGB image stored in fIplImageHeader to a JPEG image. For a 640*480 image it takes about 0.25 seconds to execute the five lines above.

Is there any way I could make it faster? I really need to repeat the compression more than 4 times a second.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using [`libjpeg-turbo`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libjpeg-turbo/) instead of `libjpeg`, it has MMX & SSE optimizations.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind spending money - consider Intel Performance Primitives - it is blazing fast. AMD has Framewave supposed to API-compatible - I haven't tried it.
BTW - check this link [Fast JPEG encoding library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/868966/fast-jpeg-encoding-library)