# How to decode JPEG files faster?

Tags: performance, delphi, delphi-xe2, jpeg

Delphi's default JPEG library is extremely slow. How to improve its performance? I need to be faster on saving and loading jpeg images.

I have tested only the Jpeg.TJPEGImage

Comment: I have tested only the Jpeg.TJPEGImage

Comment: How much faster than that do you want your code to be? And what sort of images are you working with?

Comment: Thanks for support David! The image size is 800x600 or 960x800. The image size 83-100kb. It was saved/compress using the Delphi's Jpeg.TJPEGImage.. I am looking for a better class to compress and load images(at least to save/compress the image from a TBitmap)

Comment: How much better? What is the problem with `TJPEGImage`?

Comment: libJPEG has SIMD variants. There's also Intel's IPP. http://www.briancbecker.com/blog/2010/analysis-of-jpeg-decoding-speeds/ If you won't tell us what the current performance is, and how fast you need it to be, it's hard to know what to recommend.

Comment: I receive about 30 frames per second from my webcam(the component gives me bitmap) so I built a multi-threading solution using critical sections and queues to save my frames(I can control how much CPU to be used by these threads)

Comment: Currently my threads can save about 25-26 frames per second, and I would like to know if there is a library with Jpeg compression faster

Comment: TJPEGImage is 25% faster in a 64 bit process. Don't know if that could help.

Comment: @David I must compile and build my project as a 64 bit application?

Comment: I have no idea how fast this library is, [NativeJpg](http://www.simdesign.nl/nativejpg.html), but you can download the trial library and test.

Comment: Synapse has currently the fastest decoder I have found for Delphi, 5-6 times faster than native TJpegImage and still faster than libjpeg and Intel's. Some bench: http://synopse.info/forum/viewtopic.php?id=1940 it's their "SSE2 fast jpeg decoder". The next fastest one is through their GDIPlus library.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/868966/fast-jpeg-encoding-library?rq=1

Comment: http://www.briancbecker.com/blog/2010/analysis-of-jpeg-decoding-speeds/

Answer (score 3):

You could use libJpeg or libJpegTurbo. The latter is definitely very fast.

From unit:

```
{
libJPEG Header conversion by Steffen Xonna. (21-03-2008)

http://www.dev-center.de/index.php?cat=header&file=libjpeg


Below you find an copy from the original libJPEG header.

/* jpeglib.h
 *
 * Copyright (C) 1991-1998, Thomas G. Lane.
 * This file is part of the Independent JPEG Group's software.
 * For conditions of distribution and use, see the accompanying README file.
 *
 * This file defines the application interface for the JPEG library.
 * Most applications using the library need only include this file,
 * and perhaps jerror.h if they want to know the exact error codes.
 */
}
```

Comment: The latest jp jpeglib is the fastest for very large images, however for average and small jpegs synopse's SSE2 native decoder is still the fastest.

Comment: @Rigel libjpegturbo? You need the interface unit (google it) and then read the documentation on how to call it.

Comment: I just did some quick timing comparing libJpegTurbo with Synopse JpegDec 1.02. libJpegTurbo was consistently about twice as fast. (0.01 seconds vs 0.02 seconds each for several HD pictures). That's just on my (very fast) machine and by no means an extensive performance comparison.

Answer (score 0):

We have a JPEG decompressor which will decompress over 350 Megapixels per second (over 700 Megapixels if restart markers in code). Also extract over 3000 thumbnails per second. This does not include the time to read compressed code into memory. Look at www.instantimage.com. Also very solid and will decompress many JPEG images which Microsoft windows software will not.

Comment: note: as 2019, the site seems abandoned. pages are not working.

Comment: note: the library is commercial. no price listed.

Comment: note: the library might not be native Delphi (maybe only a DLL).

Comment: note: no demo available. only a statement that it is fast.